# The use of char arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am currently working on a Tic Tac Toe assignment using java. They asked me to use char array in it, but I am not sure about how to use char arrays, and what kind of values does it store inside?

Comment: Hint: `char[] cArray = new char[5]; cArray[0] = 'a';`

Comment: So, a `char` array is a simplified `String`, this would, presumably, allow you to iterate over the array and check to see if the user input matches the "secret" word and also to determine what the user has entered...

Comment: A char array is an array of chars. Do you know what an array is and what a char is?

Comment: @MadProgrammer telling someone who doesn't know what a `char[]` is that a `char[]` is a simplified form of a `String` seems... suboptimal. The primary differences between `char[]` and `String` are 1) `String` has a whole bunch of built in methods that `char[]` does not (which is, I assume, what you were saying above). 2) `String` is immutable while `char` is not.

Comment: @k_g So `String` is wrapper/container around `char[]`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes...

Answer (score 2):

`char` arrays store multiple `char` values.

A `char` is a single character (letter/number/symbol) wrapped with single quote marks: `'L'`.

To create an array variable, specify the type of the array, followed by `[]`, followed by an identifier (name).

```
char[] myArray;
```

Initializing an array is somewhat similar to initializing an object: use the `new` keyword, specify the type of the array, then specify how many array indexes (how many valuws the array can store) wrapped in `[ ]`

```
 char[] myArray = new char[10]; //10 indexes; 0 to 9
```

To store a value in the array, access an index by specifying the array name followed by the index wrapped in `[ ]`:

```
 myArray[0] = 'c';
```

Accessing the value is similar:

```
char letter = myArray[0];
```

You can also specify values when initializing the array:

```
char[] myArray = { 'c', 'a' };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare array of characters as
char[] anArrayOfChars; 
Refer this [link] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) 
for more details.
Also, here's [a link] (http://www.coderslexicon.com/a-beginner-tic-tac-toe-class-for-java/) for sample code for tic-tac-toe implemented in Java.